# Moderator Tools > Flags has spelling errors

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

In the headings of the help text on the right-hand side of the [Moderator Tools > Flags](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tools?s=1&tab=flags) page, the two instances of the word "I" should be capitalized. I recognize that these headings have a lowercase-only motif; the word "I", as a proper noun (proper pronoun?) should be capitalized anyway.

Comment: As I don't have access to any other site's mod tools, I can't check them, so I posted here. If this is endemic (as I suspect), I'll be happy to assist in the moving of this question to MSO.

Comment: You can call the lower-case letters a "mofif"; I call it an error.

Comment: @DanielLawson The sentences don't start with capital letters; I assumed that was deliberate. It could be an error, in which they should be fixed, too.

Comment: The developers monitor the bug tag on all sites the last I heard so it's not necessary to migrate to the main meta. Flag it if you'd like that as it's clearly something not specific to our site.

Comment: @bmike I tend to consider incorrect capitalization (in cases like this) to be a spelling error.

Comment: I'm flattening [tag:spelling] and [tag:grammar] to design since that covers the site design as a whole - type, copy and graphics. I agree with you in the real world this would be a spelling / proofreading issue with the copy.

Comment: @CajunLuke It might have been deliberate, but an error made deliberately is still an error :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree the proofreading there is non-standard. Let's see what the site developers think...

[image: Typos in the flag page]

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: Thanks. (extra chars)